# Is LDAP a TCP or a UDP protocol?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I have got some wireshark captures, and it shows that it is UDP. But in theory it says that it uses both TCP and UDP. So I m confused. And what is the difference b/w LDAP and CLDAP? Are they both UDP protocols?

Answer (score 24):

Normally LDAP is a TCP protocol. But Microsoft uses LDAP also over UDP. See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc717362(v=prot.10).aspx

So it is both.

Answer (score 4):

Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP)
The Lightweight Directory Access Protocol: The protocol accessing data from directory services like OpenLDAP, Microsoft Active Directory, Netscape Directory Server or Novell eDirectory.

Protocol dependencies
TCP/UDP: Typically, LDAP uses TCP or UDP (aka CLDAP) as its transport protocol. The well known TCP and UDP port for LDAP traffic is 389.

SSL/TLS: LDAP can also be tunneled through SSL/TLS encrypted connections. The well known TCP port for SSL is 636 while TLS is negotiated within a plain TCP connection on port 389.

https://wiki.wireshark.org/LDAP